# unbound anycast resolver stopped caching

Tags: unbound

The log message indicates that Unbound is not serving any cached responses for the queries received on thread 0. Additionally, it shows that 11 queries were made, all of which required recursion (no answers were found in the cache), and no queries were answered from cache.

Why the caching stopped working and the same configuration were working for years..

Comment: On further check  caching problem is related to the subnetcache module , if i disable the caching works.